# Saw this at my local chinese grocery

Tags: food-safety, chinese-cuisine, food-identification

[image]

This was near the seafood section in a big vat of ice at my local chinese grocery.  What the heck is this?

Comment: Looks like cubes of pig's blood but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: I was thinking it was congealed blood.  Google image search seems to verify

Comment: Errrm, why didn't you ask them? (I guess "don't speak Chinese" would be a good answer)

Comment: the people at this place won't talk to you if you're not chinese, you will be actively ignored.  but they have calamari for super cheap so, meh.

Comment: It's pig's blood, they come in plastic containers in Toronto, my wife gets it all the time

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pretty sure it is congealed pig's blood. It's commonly seen in SEA (South East Asian) countries and Hong Kong. It is used as an ingredient in some dishes and in Malaysia, I have seen it been used in soup as well as soup based noodles.

One way to identify them is that they are always sold in cubed form.

update: sometimes, chicken blood is sold/used in the same form.